# C++: enable_shared_from_this и деструктор

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointer, деструктор

Насколько я понимаю, в enable_shared_from_this определен свой деструктор. Как мне написать свой деструктор, в котором нужно закрыть файловый дескриптор, так, чтобы все отработало корректно?

```
class Example: public std::enable_shared_from_this {
    ...
   ~Example() {
        ::close(fdout);
    }
};
```

Comment: а чем тот факт, что у enable_shared_from_this есть деструктор мешает просто написать свой как есть?

Comment: Мб так и правильно, я ничего не утверждаю. Но IDE ругается: Destructor '~Example' hides a non virtual function from class 'enable_shared_from_this'.

Comment: Clang. IDE - Clion. Код компилируется, вопрос в том - правильно ли это будет работать.

Comment: вроде будет, так как удаление объекта будет вызываться в одном из деструкторов `shared_ptr`, а там будет вызван `delete` от указателя на `Example`, а не от указателя на `enable_shared_from_this`, а так можно делать, по крайней мере [в этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7403943/5812238) так написано

Comment: работать будет, если только какое-нибудь особое извращение не записать, удалив приведя к std::enable_shared_from_this. А вот как собрать, чтобы убрать ворнинг не подскажу... на linux'е с гнутой libc++ не воспроизводится... так что может быть дело в либе... могу предложить собирать с `-stdlib=libstdc++` вместо `-stdlib=libc++`, если устроит.

Comment: Что-то типа этого дописать в деструкторе? `delete (enable_shared_from_this<Example>*)(this);` Да это не важно, главное чтобы работало. Создайте ответ тогда.

Comment: Порылся в memory. Там вообще пустой деструктор `~enable_shared_from_this() {}`. А в linux-е его по ходу нет. Наверное это моя паранойя, хотя в случае C++ лучше лишний раз запараноиться)

Comment: Не воспроизводится. Clang и g++ компилируют молча.

Comment: Так ругается IDE или компилятор?

Comment: Croessmah, IDE ругается, компилятор - нет. Все работает правильно, деструктор моего класса вызывается.